# Maven sure-fire plugin is not running second test class for the same original class

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have original test class named OriginalTestClass and two test classes for it that bring testing upon different method of OriginalTestClass. Their names are:

- OriginalTestClassTest
- OriginalTestClassTestNotParameterized

I can see that only the first test class OriginalTestClassTest was run and OriginalTestClassTestNotParameterized was not. Why is that? Any settings for that?

Comment: The classes have to end in a specific pattern, normally `*Test.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the plugin uses class names convention in order to identify test classes. You should change the second class name to something like
`OriginalTestClassNotParameterizedTest` or `TestOriginalTestClassNotParameterized`

See [test goal includes parameter](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) for more

Answer (score 1):

The naming convention is your problem...cause the [naming schema is like](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes) this:

```xml
<includes>
 <include>**/Test*.java</include>
 <include>**/*Test.java</include>
 <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

The class `OriginalTestClassTestNotParameterized` does not follow this schema and that's the reason why it is not running. You could of course change the configuration but i would recomment to follow the naming schema.